# Jenkins deploy plugin - pass parameters from properties file

Tags: jenkins

I'm using Jenkins and deploy plugin, with which I'm deploying to tomcat server. How can I pass parameters from properties file to this deploy plugin?

for example I want to pass my property app.server.url to Tomcat URL field.

I tried to pass `$app.server.url` also `%app.server.url%`, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have a properties file in the format `app.server.url=somevalue`

You then can inject these properties into the Jenkins environment using [EnvInjec Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin). Use **Inject environment variables for your job** build step, and just specify your file path (leave the *content* field blank). After that, you can reference it like this `$app.server.url` for *nix, or `%app.server.url%` for Windows. However this only works on the shell level. On the plugin properties level, a lot of plugins are expecting properties only in *nix-style format.

The further problem is that *nix-style variables do **not** allow dots `.`. So `$app.server.url` is not valid on *nix. I do not know if it will work on plugin-level on Windows though.

So after setting up EnvInject plugin, try the following two:

- Try using `$app.server.url` in your deploy plugin.
- Else change the property file to something like `app_server_url=somevalue`, and then try `$app_server_url` in deploy plugin.

Comment: hmm this is not working for me :( I'm on windows, and inject plugin seems to work properly, but when I reference this property in deploy plugin I'm still getting error java.lang.AssertionError: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: %app.server%/manager

Comment: OK. Internally Jenkins still uses `$var` notation, so a lot of plugins only recognize that, even if on Windows. You will have to use `$var` notation, but remember that *nix-style variables cannot have a dot `.` in the name, so change your properties file. I will update answer

Comment: no that does not work :( [EnvInject] - Injecting as environment variables the properties content 
appServer=[http://testserver:8050](http://testserver:8050) and return is>>>>>>>   java.lang.AssertionError: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: $appServer/manager

Comment: Was going to link you [this](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22403?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin:activity-stream-issue-tab) but I think you created that :)

Comment: Slav yes that's my jira SR. And ${appServer} doesn't work also.